# Mysql_fetch_array supplied argument is not a valid MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, runner

I'm getting this error message: "Mysql_fetch_array supplied argument is not a valid MYSQL result" but I don't know whats wrong with the code

```
$sql = "SELECT *, status_pedido.nome as descricao_status,frete.nome as nome_frete, historico.data as data_hist, DATE_FORMAT(historico.`data`,'%d/%m/%Y') as data, DATE_FORMAT(historico.`data`,'%H:%i:%s ') as hora
                    FROM midiosto_db.`l-pedidos` as pedido
                    INNER JOIN midiosto_db.`l-pedido-historico` as historico
                        ON pedido.id = historico.`id-pedido`
                    INNER JOIN midiosto_db.`l-status` as status_pedido
                        ON status_pedido.id = historico.`id-status`
                    INNER JOIN midiosto_db.`l-frete` as frete
                        On frete.id = pedido.`id-frete`
                    WHERE pedido.id  = ".$_GET["id_pedido"]."
                    ORDER BY data_hist DESC";

$query_historico = mysql_query($sql);
$row_historico = mysql_fetch_array($query_historico);
```

Comment: First change `mysql_query($sql);` to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and see if you get an error.

Comment: Also note that `mysql_` functions should no longer be used. Use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: **Before you post a question asking "What does this error message mean?" do a search in the search box for the actual error message.**  There you will find other questions from people who have had the exact same problem, and then you can learn how they solved it.

Comment: did you put 'or die' behind the mysql_query($sql) as well?

Comment: @FDL I got SELECT command denied to user 'midiosto_sys'@'localhost' for table 'l-pedidos'

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to SQL inection with this code... get is no secure at all. Use PDO instead mysql_query.

And for your error message, query_historico  is probably not of the type you expect because your SQL statement is maybe wrong.

Comment: Using PDO is not enough.  The user must use prepared statements.  PDO is open to SQL injection if the user creates SQL statements with untrusted data.

Comment: I agree, of course @Andy Lester